# MapReduce job using Hbase table as source and sink within Spring XD batch job

Tags: spring, mapreduce, hbase

How can we configure MapReduce Job which uses Hbase tables as source and sink within Spring, I am planning create batch job withing Spring XD which uses mapreduce job , but I want to use Hbase tables as source and sink to this hadoop job.  Something similar  TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(), TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob()

`<hdp:job>` namespace currently does not support providing input/output tables

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using another bean which takes the hadoop job as input and returns the job after setting Scan() and source and sink Hbase tables. Using the scope="job" on  and scope="prototype" on  I was able to run the same MR job multiple times in the spring XD, without this you will get Job is in RUNNING state instead of DEFINE state issue after the first successful run.

```
public class InitJobTasklet {
   private Job job;


    public void setJob(Object job){
     this.job = (Job)job;
    }

     public Job getJob() throws IOException {


         Scan scan = new Scan();
         System.out.println("Initializing the hadoop job with hbase tables and scan object... ");
         TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("SourceTable", 
                                        scan, 
                                        Mapper.class,
                                        Text.class, Result.class, job);

         TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                "TargetTable",      // output table
                Reducer.class,             // reducer class
                job);
                job.setNumReduceTasks(1);


          return job;
 }
```

}

spring batch job config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">


<hdp:job id="mr-hbase-job"
    output-path="/output"
  mapper="mapperclass" reducer="reduceclass"
  map-key="org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable" map-value="org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result" input-format="org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat" output-format="org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat" jar-by-class="processor class" scope="prototype">

</hdp:job>

<batch:job id="job"  >
              <batch:step id="step1">
        <hdp:job-tasklet id="hadoop-tasklet" job="#{initTask.job}" wait-for-completion="true"  scope="job"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>



<hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
     fs.defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:9000
 hadoop.tmp.dir=/home/smunigati/hadoop/temp
 hbase.zookeeper.quorum=localhost
 hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
    </hdp:configuration>

<hdp:hbase-configuration id="hbaseConfiguration" configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration">
</hdp:hbase-configuration>


   <bean id="initTask" class="com.somthing.InitJobTasklet" scope="prototype" >
    <property name="job" ref="mr-hbase-job" />  
    </bean>
```